# How to determine the original matrix size from the result generated from `fftw_dft_r2c`?

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

For `fftw3`, if you perform Reals 2D FFT on a matrix A with size of [m x n], you would get a complex matrix B with size of [m x (n/2 + 1)]. If we only have B, how to determine A's shape, i.e. rows and cols of A?

For 1D FFT problems, I get to know that performing `fft` on `vector` with odd size results in a complex vector ends with a real number, i.e. `vector_fft[-1].imag() == 0`. And this can be the key to determine the original `vector` size.

However, for 2D FFT, problem seems to be more complicated, there is no such evident feature for 2D FFT-ed array. I read the manual of [`fftw3`](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html), and still be confused with how `fftw` compressed the conjugated data in result matrix.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <complex>

#define EIGEN_DEFAULT_TO_ROW_MAJOR

using namespace Eigen;

using Cmpl  = std::complex<double>;

using Matd  = Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>;
using Vecd  = Matrix<double,       1, Dynamic, RowMajor>;
using Veccd = Matrix<  Cmpl,       1, Dynamic, RowMajor>;
using Matcd = Matrix<  Cmpl, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>;

Veccd fft_1d_r2c(const Vecd& in) {
  Veccd out(in.size() / 2 + 1);
  auto plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(in.size(),
      (double*)in.data(), (fftw_complex*)out.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  return out;
}

Veccd fft_1d_c2c(const Veccd& in) {
  Veccd out(in.size());
  auto plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(in.size(),
      (fftw_complex*)in.data(), (fftw_complex*)out.data(),
      FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  return out;
}

Matcd fft_2d_r2c(const Matd& in) {
  Matcd out(in.rows(), in.cols() / 2 + 1);
  auto plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(in.rows(), in.cols(),
      (double*)in.data(), (fftw_complex*)out.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  return out;
}

Matcd fft_2d_c2c(const Matcd& in) {
  Matcd out(in.rows(), in.cols());
  auto plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(in.rows(), in.cols(),
      (fftw_complex*)in.data(), (fftw_complex*)out.data(),
      FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  return out;
}

void test_1d(const int size) {
  Vecd vec{size};
  vec.setRandom();
  Veccd vec_fft = fft_1d_c2c(vec.cast<Cmpl>());
  Veccd vec_rfft = fft_1d_r2c(vec);
  std::cout << "Original Vector: \n" << vec << std::endl << std::endl
    << "fftw_r2c of vec: \n" << vec_rfft << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void test_2d(const int rows, const int cols) {
  Matd mat{rows, cols};
  mat.setRandom();

  Matcd mat_rfft = fft_2d_r2c(mat);
  Matcd mat_fft = fft_2d_c2c(mat.cast<Cmpl>());
  std::cout << "Original Matrix: \n" << mat << std::endl << std::endl
    << "fftw_r2c of mat: \n" << mat_rfft << std::endl << std::endl;

  std::cout << "fftw_c2c of mat: \n" << mat_fft << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << "For 1D fft problems" << std::endl;
  test_1d(9);
  test_1d(10);

  std::cout << "For 2D fft problems" << std::endl;
  test_2d(6, 5);
  test_2d(6, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

For the matrix returned by `fftw_r2c`, how to determine the shape of original matrix?

Comment: It seems I should put `#define EIGEN_DEFAULT_TO_ROW_MAJOR` before `#include <Eigen/Eigen>` ..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If `vector_fft[-1].imag() == 0` prooves a good criteria, the same trick can be applied to 2D r2c dfts. First, a 1D r2c dft is performed on the cols. If this size is odd, then the last complex item of each column is purely real. Then the second c2c dft is performed on the rows. The last row is purely real. Hence, the average of the last row is purely real: it happens to be the first item of the last row at the end of the 2D r2c dft.Consequently, a test like `If matrix_fft[-1][0].imag() == 0` or `If matrix_fft[0][-1].imag() == 0` might do the trick.

Comment: @francis I got it, you're right, `matrix_fft[0][-1].imag()` do `== 0`.